# How i can call request.security on ta.sar (pinescript/TradingView)?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I need to call a ta.sar in heikin ashi security, that gives me a buy/sell signal to execute in japanise candles values.

```
//SAR security example (not working)
start = input(0.02)
increment = input(0.02)
maximum = input(0.2, "Max Value")
out = (request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close) ta.sar(start, increment, maximum))
sarColor = out < low ? color.lime : color.red
plot(out, "ParabolicSAR", style=plot.style_cross, color=sarColor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request.security()` function 3rd paramter is the `expression` you wish to return. In you case, you're requesting `Close`, while you want to get sar. You also use an extra parenthesis you can delete from your code:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Money Flow Index", shorttitle="MFI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
start = input(0.02)
increment = input(0.02)
maximum = input(0.2, "Max Value")
out = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, ta.sar(start, increment, maximum))
sarColor = out < low ? color.lime : color.red
plot(out, "ParabolicSAR", style=plot.style_cross, color=sarColor)
```

You can get both Close and sar if you wish using Close at a later time:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Money Flow Index", shorttitle="MFI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
start = input(0.02)
increment = input(0.02)
maximum = input(0.2, "Max Value")
[_close, out] = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, [close, ta.sar(start, increment, maximum)])
sarColor = out < low ? color.lime : color.red
plot(out, "ParabolicSAR", style=plot.style_cross, color=sarColor)
plot(_close)
```